# Sorting Result Sets in Crystal or SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, crystal-reports

I asked one of our report writers to sort result sets coming from SQL Server in Crystal instead of SQL Server because, generally, SQL Server sort operations are very expensive operations. His response was this, "It actually takes far more time to sort and format the data in Crystal, as it has to pull all the data into the report file itself first, then determine the order as it’s rendering."

I haven't used Crystal in years. I find it hard to believe this is accurate. Is this the case?

Comment: I don't know much about CR either, but usually the argument for sorting in the application is that app CPU time is dirt cheap while SQL CPU time is ludicrously expensive. It has less to do with speed, and more to do with not using your precious SQL Server cores for work that can be done more easily by cheaper CPUs.

Comment: That sounds like an urban myth to me. What happens when the application allows you to specify sorting? Does this same person think you should retrieve a new dataset instead of sorting the one you already have? I would ask them for some examples or posts somewhere where somebody actually did some performance testing.